# Not able to create Pull Request in VS 2022 Professional

Tags: visual-studio, pull-request

I'm new to using source control is Visual Studio (VS 2022, Professional Edition).  After I've made changes to a feature branch, committed changes, and then pushed to remote I don't see the link to create a PR in the message.  The 'New Pull Request' menu item under the Git/Azure DevOps menu item is also greyed out. So the only option I have now is to go to the Azure DevOps website and create the PR there, which works fine.

My VS version is 17.7.7.

Does anyone have any ideas on why I'm not able to create a PR from within Visual Studio ?

Answer (score 2):

I found a fix for my problem. I noticed in the top right corner of VS where my initials were showing, that VS was asking me to re-enter my credentials.  Just re-entering the credentials got me logged in, but didn't solve the problem.  I had to exist VS and then open it up again.  Once I did that, I'm now getting the link to create a PR and the PR menu item under Git is also no longer greyed out.

Answer (score 1):

If you open the `Team Explorer` window in Visual Studio 2022 you need to connect to your repository from there before the pull request option are no longer greyed out. Team Explorer window can be found via main menu: `View -> Team Explorer`.

You will then need to `Manage Connections` at the top of tool window (little plug icon). Then select and connect to your repo. This enabled the pull request options for me.